# Create foreign key to a non-primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to create a foreign key constraint to a non-primary key column which is `UNIQUE`? I'm using `PostgreSQL 8.4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

From [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-constraints.html):

> Finally, we should mention that a foreign key must reference columns
>   that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint.